# Vendor CSS files not being compiled for Brunch

Tags: brunch

I am having an issue with brunch@1.7.6 not compiling bower_component css files. Similar to [Separating app and vendor css in Brunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934237/separating-app-and-vendor-css-in-brunch). Only the css/app.css is getting generated for me. :/

```
{
  stylesheets: {
    joinTo: {
      'css/app.css': /^app/,
      'css/vendor.css': /^bower_components/
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. All seemed fine when I was using brunch@1.6.7. Did the config change with the introduction to bower being built in?

Comment: Looks alright, it should work. This https://gist.github.com/paulmillr/6668969 worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you don't have any CSS files in bower components

Comment: You could try the same what I've answered in the [mentioned question][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18977304/549808

Comment: Realizing that the question is old, but it may be useful for future readers: make sure that the `bower_components` sub-directories containing the vendor CSS files are "watched" by Brunch (`paths` -> `watched` section).

Answer (score 2):

With regards to `x-editable`, I ran into the failure to include the `bower_components` css, but found that I simply had to add the specifics in the overrides section of `bower.json` (since it has multiple library options the main is not included in the `.bower.json`).

I used the following overrides successfully:

```
"overrides": {
    "x-editable": {
        "main": [
            "dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js",
            "dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css"
        ]
    }
}
```