# Brunch bower_component CSS not compiling? (Fancybox)

Tags: css, bower, fancybox-2, brunch

I've tried to follow all these other threads but am unable to get this to work for some reason:

[Vendor CSS files not being compiled for Brunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945353/vendor-css-files-not-being-compiled-for-brunch)

[Separating app and vendor css in Brunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934237/separating-app-and-vendor-css-in-brunch)

For some reason, I'm unable to get brunch to ouput vendor CSS at all?

The particular package I'm talking about is [Fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox) which has a css file `source/jquery.fancybox.css`.

I've overridden the fancybox `main` in my `bower.json` (as no main is included in the package). For some reason, no css is output, only the javascript. I feel like I must be doing something trivially wrong as no errors are output either and I even see the css file as being watched in the debug output?

Output of `brunch b -Pd`:

```
❯ brunch b -Pd > brunch-debug.txt
  brunch:watch Loaded plugins: javascript-brunch, sass-brunch +0ms
  brunch:watch File 'package.json' received event 'add' +5ms
  brunch:watch File 'bower.json' received event 'add' +1ms
  brunch:watch File 'brunch-config.coffee' received event 'add' +0ms
  brunch:file-list Reading 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js' +1ms
  brunch:watch File 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js' received event 'add' +0ms
  brunch:file-list Reading 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css' +0ms
  brunch:watch File 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css' received event 'add' +0ms
  brunch:source-file Initializing fs_utils.SourceFile: {"path":"bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js","isntModule":true,"isWrapped":true} +1ms
  brunch:pipeline Compiling 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js' with 'JavaScriptCompiler' +1ms
  brunch:file-list Compiled file 'bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js'... +40ms
  brunch:write Writing 1/1 files +71ms
  brunch:generate Concatenating bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js to public/libraries.js +3ms
  brunch:common Writing file 'public/libraries.js' +7ms
```

I've setup my config files so:

**brunch-config.coffee**

```
module.exports = config:
  files:
    javascripts: joinTo:
      'libraries.js': /^(?!app\/)/
      'app.js': /^app\//
    stylesheets: joinTo:
      'vendor.css': /^(bower_components|vendor)\//
      'app.css': /^app\//
  modules:
    wrapper: false
    definition: false
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "brunch-test-fancybox",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Test <test@test.com>"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "overrides": {
    "fancybox": {
      "main": [
        "source/jquery.fancybox.css",
        "source/jquery.fancybox.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fancybox": "~2.1.5"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "brunch-test-fancybox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "brunch": "^1.8.5",
    "javascript-brunch": "^1.7.1",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the css-brunch plugin to your project, otherwise Brunch does not know how you want to handle `.css` files.

Comment: And of course, yes it was a completely trivial mistake on my part haha. Thank you. A simple `npm install --save-dev css-brunch` and it works great now.